# Using lines and derivatives instructions

Tags: opengl, glsl, derivative

I'd like to know if derivatives in glsl are working on `GL_LINES` primitives.

AFAIK OpenGL implementations perform a discrete approximation on a group of 4 pixels (2x2 pixel quad) to compute derivative.
Could it be possible to make them work on 1 pixel width lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, mipmapping and derivatives work on line primitives.